# JSON Decode save array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am able to receive the following JSON data with the following PHP code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://xxxx');
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$forex = $data['items'];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($forex);
exit;
```

This gives me the following JSON data:

```
Array
  (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [new] => 
        [data] => Array
            (
                [direction] => 1
                [pip] => 0
                [exchange] => FOREX
                [symbol] => USDCHF
                [interval] => 15
                [pattern] => Resistance
                [complete] => 
                [identified] => 2020-02-26T14:45:00.000Z
                [age] => 0
                [length] => 259
                [found] => 2020-02-26T14:45:56.381Z
                [result_type] => KeyLevel
                [result_uid] => 642525551
                [prediction_price_from] => 0
                [prediction_price_to] => 0
                [group_name] => FX Majors
                [symbol_name] => USDCHF
                [symbol_id] => 0
                [analysis_text] => Approaching Resistance level of 0.9800 identified at 2/26 14:45. This pattern is still in the process of forming. Possible bullish price movement towards the resistance 0.9800 within the next 15 hours.
                [expires_at] => 2020-02-27T05:48:36.701Z
            )

        [links] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [rel] => detail
                        [href] => https://xxxx
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [rel] => analysis
                        [href] => https://xxxx
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [rel] => chart-xs
                        [href] => https://xxxx
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [rel] => chart-sm
                        [href] => https://xxxx
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [rel] => chart-md
                        [href] => https://xxxx
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [rel] => chart-lg
                        [href] => https://xxxx
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [rel] => icon-arrow
                        [href] => https://xxxx
                    )

            )

    )
```

What I am trying to do is to save the information into my MySQL database, however I am unable to get the data displayed even by testing to echo the data:

```
foreach($forex as $info) { 
echo $info->symbol . '<br>';
}
```

Anyone with a possible solution for me to save the data or even enable me to display the data for each Array (Example: symbol, pattern, link chart-md).

Comment: Did you mean `$info['data']['symbol']`? Do you get any errors (if so, which is it)?

Comment: You are not at the right level. Right now, your foreach is going over the outermost level of this - so each $info will be the sub-array containing the keys `new`, `data`, etc. You need to access `data` now first from the current position, and then `symbol` inside that. And you have _arrays_ here, not objects - so no `->` in the first place.

Comment: @kerbholz when trying your suggestion no data is displayed.

Comment: @CBroe any suggestions to what i can add or modify to the code?

Comment: What was suggested in the first comment should work. If it doesn’t for you, then give us a proper [mre], please. Show your data either in JSON form or a `var_export` of it, and show us _exactly_ what you are trying to do in your code to access it now.

Comment: @CBroe Apologies, I had a typo in my code, all working now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below the commented code:

```
//Save json text into variable $json
$json = file_get_contents('https://xxxx');

//Convert json into PHP array
$data = json_decode($json,true);

//Set $forex as $data['items'];
$forex = $data['items'];

//Print
echo "<pre>";
print_r($forex);
exit;
```

`$forex` is a PHP array variable (not a JSON string).

You could save your data into MySQL `VARCHAR[Length]` field using json string variable `$json` instead of PHP array `$forex`.

When you need to get the data from DB and display it, you could get JSON data from MySQL and convert it from JSON to Array using PHP `json_decode($json,true)`.

If you want to use a value into a PHP array, use $info["symbol"] instead of `$info->symbol`